# Wcf communication between two windows in different threads?

Tags: wpf, wcf, window

Suppose from the main wpf window (WMain) I create a number of instances of other windows (WA, WB WC ..) all of the same type WModel and each on a seperate thread.

Would the following be a good idea for exchanging information between WMain and WModel?
I am considering to let WMain host a wcf service that can be called from WModel.
And also let WModel host another wcf service that can be called form WMain.

Performance will not be an issue as the communication is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use something like WFC if all of the windows are running in the same process.

WCF is for communication between external processes.

If you want to do communication between threads in the same process there are plenty of patterns, starting with something as simple as a threadsafe singleton as a global state container, to using something like a event bus to push events from publishers / subscribers.

Comment: Ok. I thnik I could use both "threadsafe singleton" and "event bus". Do you know whether this is built-in in .NET BCL? Any simple examples?